# In PoW networks, how do weak miners get reward while powerful miners present?

Tags: blockchain

According to [this Jimi S. article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/what-is-a-51-attack-or-double-spend-attack-aa108db63474)

> The more computational power a miner has, the better their chances are to find a solution before other miners find theirs.

As I understood that quote, if another miner computes hash faster than you, your attempt to mine is discarded.

**Does it mean that in PoW systems weak miners have an extremely rare but significant discrete reward**? (instead of a continuous tiny one)

In more details, by "rare but significant reward" I mean this process: if a miner has little computational power, it

1. tries to compute a transaction hash
2. most probably fails because a more powerful miner takes the same transaction to compute and computes it faster
3. repeats the process until it is lucky enough to find a nonce in far fewer iterations

Does it work like that or are there techniques to balance the reward more continuously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that in PoW systems weak miners have an extremely rare but significant discrete reward? (instead of a continuous tiny one)

Yes, but only if the miner is solo mining. If the miner is mining in a [pool](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pooled_mining), then they do get a continuous reward. Today, most (basically all) mining in Bitcoin is done in pools. This is because it would take a very large amount of hashpower in order to generate any sort of predictable income, which is needed to cover operating costs.

### Mining Pools

The way a mining pool works is miners submit "shares". A share is just a block hash that the miner computed that meets a minimum [difficulty](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty). Sometimes, but rarely, this block hash is good enough to create a valid block (a win a block reward). Most often, however, it is not enough, so the pool will award that miner a portion of the next block (when someone in the pool finds a valid hash). The difficulty of all the miners' shares over the period of time it takes for someone in the pool to mine a block determines how the block reward is split between all the miners.